# Does async/await makes simple thing unnecessary complicated?

Tags: c#, windows-8, metro

After exposing to Windows App Store development for a month, I begin to feel that `async` / `await` programming model does more harm than good. **It makes simple thing complicated.**

Take an example, folder creation. In Java or Desktop .NET, I can simply do

### Java

```
public Constructor()
{
    new File("c:\\folder").mkdirs();
    System.out.println("I am pretty sure c:\\folder is ready now");
}
```

### Desktop .NET

```
Constructor()
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\folder");
    Console.WriteLine("I am pretty sure c:\\folder is ready now");
}
```

But when comes to

### Windows App Store .NET

```
Constructor()
{
    // Damm it! Another async function? I don't need aysnc!
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("c:\\folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    // I am not sure c:\\folder is ready right now!
    // OK. I know I can use ContinueWith. No no no. I don't want.
    // Why I have to use ContinueWith with such a simple operation?
}
```

So, my question is, do you find the newly introduced `async` / `await` programming model in Windows App Store,

- Improve your productivity?
- Make programming life easier?

**For me, I don't!** Perhaps I have been missing out certain useful techniques.

I know, Microsoft says, it helps us to write responsive UI code.

But I would say, **No thanks! Hey look, my code is already in non-UI code!**

Most of my current operation code is fast enough and doesn't block UI. When my operation code is not fast enough, I am pretty comfortable in making those slow operation code run in separate Thread/ Task.

Forcing me to use `async` / `await` which I do not need, only makes my code more complicated.

**Message to Microsoft** : May I beg to you, besides async functions, can you provide a same set of non-async functions, please? I already build up my habit of running code in non-UI thread. I promise I will continue make your Windows App perform as smooth as iOS :)

Comment: It allows you to write responsive UI code without having to move all I/O operations to a separate thread.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with windows 8, but any sort of restriction on creating directories comes from that API. Nobody's forcing you to use async for everything, all of the synchronous methods are still there.

Comment: How much async code have you written? It is _complicated_ and difficult to get right. `async` and `await` make it much easier by making the compiler do the hard work. The Java and "Desktop .NET" examples you gave are synchronous, not asynchronous. Rewrite them as asynchronous functions in both languages, without `async` and `await`, then come back to this question.

Comment: So far, I had written 1 : http://apptivate.ms/apps/78/whats-my-heart-rate

Comment: @Oded The problem is, in most of the situation I had encountered, I don't need them to be in async. I am pretty comfortable in using Task/ Thread. 90% of my non-operation code are already run in non UI thread.

Comment: The async/await make things much easier. The problem is, that some methods in Windows Phone and Win8 have only asynchronous versions and nothing else and you have to use it even if you are doing your work in non-UI thread. As someone on Channel9 said "With great responsivness comes great responsibility" :)

Comment: @Ondra Morský Ya. I get your point. What I really want to bring out is, Microsoft should provide both async and non-aysnc of functions. We, developers, are smart enough to choose in between.

Comment: [Futures (promises)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_%28programming%29 "what's this") are the way to go

Comment: I think the goal of this API was to allow anyone to write responsive app, with the tradeoff of "worse" code in advaced scenarios (background threads etc.)

Comment: You're using the wrong comparison. You're comparing the old synchronous operations with new asynchronous operations, to make clear what you're replacing you should compare the old asynchronous operations with the new asynchronous operations, and you will then see that the new technique is simpler. Also the new approach is naturally faster due to the plumbing of when it actually becomes a separate thread

Comment: @JimmyHoffa You are right, about making it simpler with async/await keywords, but in desktop .NET you have a choice of sync/async. With win8 you have to use async no mather what you want.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa No. I know they are in different programming model. I just want to show, synchronous is much simpler to write, yet able to produce responsive app. Hey, most of my code is already running in non-UI code.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK you don't understand what I'm saying, the comparison is irrational because they have completely different purposes. You wouldn't use one instead of the other so comparing them is like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: You need to understand the MS made a decision with Windows 8 - it _has_ to be responsive. This drove the `async` APIs you are talking about. MS also decided that people must write responsive UIs, so decided to not provided synchronous operations for anything that _might_ take longer the 50 milliseconds (network/disk IO etc).

Comment: @Oded OK. This is more like enforcement? Can't we have freedom?

Comment: You are not using the await/async keywords at all in your example!

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK Freedom to write unresponsive software? MS's stance with windows 8 was: No. Unresponsive software makes MS look bad, whereas enforcing highly responsive UIs will give MS an edge in marketing against apple, at least that's their belief and attempt. Makes sense, people might start saying windows is faster than apple because it appears to be so. I can say my windows phone is definitely much more responsive than my wife's android for this reason. Not to start a war, just saying there is a reason MS is enforcing these new APIs.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Start a war? How dare I :) You know, there are so many Microsoft fans around. I never try Windows Phone before. But you get your point. I can feel my Android phone is getting slower each day, as I love to try out some crappy free apps. But I don't care. As I know, freedom always come with price :) (The price seems reasonable to me)

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK - Why do you care if you are forced to use the async method?  The async method is a better way to do it.  Sounds like you should learn how to adapt to change, and learn how to do things, the correct way the first time.

Comment: slightly off topic but of course you can never be sure that the file system is in a given state, its entirely possible in your first example that another process is going around deleting your folders straight after you create them anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably [holding it wrong](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/10/09/iphone_photo_purple_glow/) *(just some context for the statement)*.

Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to play with Win8 yet, but based on code examples I've seen, your code should look more like

```
Constructor()
{
    // Damm it! Another async function? I don't need aysnc!
    var result = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("c:\\folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    // by the time your code gets to this line, the folder will have been created
}
```

The other option (if you can't make your method `async`) is to block the thread until async opertation completes by calling [GetResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206600.aspx).  Probably something along the lines of

```
Constructor()
{
    // Damm it! Another async function? I don't need aysnc!
    var result = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("c:\\folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    result.GetResults();
    result.Close(); // According to documentation, you should call this when done
    // Voila, 
}
```

---

Though it looks like you're doing file IO inside a constructor and you probably can't have `async` constructors, so the first option is out.  I assume this this is just some contrived example and not representative of your code, but my feeling is if you find yourself doing IO inside a constructor and you're not writing a framework class (like [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx)), you should take a second look at your design.  I generally don't expect newing up a class to start creating/locking system resources.

There are a couple of related questions on StackOverflow regarding constructors and async

- [Can constructors be async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)
- [start async method within object constructor - bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261173/c-sharp-start-async-method-within-object-constructor-bad-practice)

Comment: Oh, you can't use await in constructor. and believe me, if you use GetResults, it will crash with System.InvalidOperationException :) Try it and you will know. I believe after some tries, you will have the same feeling as I'm

Comment: I added some links regarding async and constructors.

Answer (score 13):

The problem here isn't the `async`/`await` keywords but the fact that many WinRT APIs are only offered in an async form. In the past, APIs have been offered in a blocking form, or your choice of blocking and non-blocking, and developers were supposed to make sure the UI didn't hang. Well guess what? Developers didn't bother. I've waited multiple minutes for a Print dialog in an Office product to finish timing out on contacting whatever printer I used last time, before I could specify that I don't want that printer, usually because that printer is now thousands of miles from me. The vast majority of applications were written the easy way for the developer even though that might create a bad experience for the user.

So the new API has no blocking form. You have to learn how to do it asynchronously, like it or not. You could set up a completed handler and then start the process, or you could use the new C# keywords. Your choice. But developers will no longer be trusted to keep the promise you offer to make. And rightly so, since almost no-one did.

Comment: We lost freedom to choose then :( You know, programmers love freedom.

Comment: You can look at it that way. Or that now you no longer have to learn two ways plus how to choose between them. That had its problems too, didn't it?

Comment: Right. Too much choices is a new set of problem :) Freedom always comes with price. Even though, I still prefer freedom more. democratic vs dictator?

Comment: Microsoft's new rule is that, if it takes more than 50ms to execute an operation, it's made into an asynchronous call.  About 10 percent of all calls in WinRT fit this definition.

Comment: From Microsoft's perspective, it is their product that would be eventually blamed --the developer will probably be too but they clearly have more at stake.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK Is losing the freedom to choose the wrong option really so terrible? Strict functional languages are highly restrictive compared to, say, C++ - and yet people who understand them are in love, in part because the restrictions mean that it's significantly harder to make incorrect choices. Eric Lippert talks about this philosophy in his post on [the Pit of Despair vs the Pit of Quality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/08/14/c-and-the-pit-of-despair.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I think, in something of a departure for Microsoft, they have thought about what makes for the best user experience rather than what makes for the easiest developer experience.

Certainly adopting the async model requires more work on the part of the developer, but just maybe gives that developer a better chance of producing something that will be responsive to the user.

You only need to use Outlook to see how bad the user experience can be if you follow a synchronous programming model too much.

Comment: +1 for the outlook comment, just previewing a mail could freeze the entire program

Comment: @Martin - An `Async` model is easier on the developers if thats their only choice.

Answer (score 2):

`await` was introduced with .NET v4.5 and is actually a way to break the pure asynchronous approach.  So it's there as a way to simplify coding with asynchronous methods / calls.

It can also be abused if you put `await` on every single one of your calls.  At that point, you're back to "traditional" coding styles where you have to wait for all actions to return.

Asynch is a useful approach when you're making calls across a network or when other actions can continue while awaiting the results of the call.  It's equivalent to using a background thread to handle some form of data processing.  The rest of the app continues along until the task is done.

As you noted in your example, there are some cases where you simply have to wait until a call completes before operations can continue.  That's where the `await` keyword comes in handy.  An alternative was to have a callback method that the performed the rest of the processing.  Honestly, that alternative is less than elegant, and I'm glad that `await` was offered up.

So, just like with any other tool:

- Use asynchronous methods as appropriate for the calls your app is making.
- Use the `await` keyword judiciously when there are calls that really must block the rest of the operations.  Don't overuse the keyword as that will hamper your application.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I think the OP might be referring to the fact that so many "Windows Store App" APIs are offered only in an async form.  Sure for your own functionality you have a choice, but when calling their API you don't.  I could be wrong though :-)

Comment: @Martin - I read the Windows Store aspect as unnecessary obfuscation of the core question.  MS has moved to requiring an async model with most of their newer development frameworks.  WCF, ASP.NET MVC v.whatever, Win8 RT, etc... require an async approach.  Since he's writing to Win8 RT | metro, he doesn't really have a choice to use async or not.  But it's not a "Windows Store" issue, per se.

Comment: Await does't block the thread, so what you are saying isn't strictly true. If you for instance await in the painting thread, no real harm is done. Blocking there would OTOH be really bad.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Async/Await makes an unnecessarily complicated thing much simpler.  (Just imagine if you had to do all that *without* Async/Await!)  The unnecessarily complicated part is Microsoft's decision to make all those APIs async-only, instead of leaving it up to the discretion of the developers.

Comment: Did Microsoft have a choice?  Based on the quality of a small but huge number of iOS applications and pretty much every Android application being so poor, and lets face it 99.9% of Windows applications have some sort of hack in them, means they had to make it required for developers to do things the proper way.  I don't think the users will complain.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the problem here is that you can't use await in a constructor and that GetResult won't work. But have you tought about using a static helper method to create your object?

```
class AsyncCreated
{
    public static async Task<AsyncCreated> CreateWithFolder()
    {
        var folder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("c:\\folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        return new AsyncCreated(folder); // There you do the usual stuff
    }

}

// elsewhere in your code

var myObject = await AsyncCreated.CreateWithFolder();
```

The added bonus is that now it's more explicit that some work is being done while you initialise the type.

Comment: In my opinion, this is one of the better more thoughtful answers to the question.  This is exactly what the OP needs - an alternative approach that illustrates how the task can be accomplished while still benefiting from the asynchronous nature of await/async calls.

Answer (score 1):

It might.

But what's probably really happening is that it is *keeping* complicated things complicated.

**Creating a file is complicated.**  It can be over a network share.  It can already exist.  The hard drive might be slow.  It might be a RAM disk.  Point is, it can take different amounts of time, or might outright fail.

[Jeff Atwood wrote a great post about this 8 years ago](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/threading-concurrency-and-the-most-powerful-psychokinetic-explosive-in-the-univ.html). He basically said that we *should* embrace multithreading and asyncronous code, but most developers aren't prepared to deal with it because it's a very complex topic, and the tools at the time weren't suitable to make it easy enough to write asynchronous code.

The `async` and `await` keywords (along with other tools, like the thread-safe collections) are Microsoft's answer to his request to improve the tools to bring easy async programming to the unwashed masses. My opinion is that they have mostly succeeded. In that a majority of cases, you can use the async APIs in WinRT as if they were not asynchronous, then just pepper in a few `async` and `await` keywords, compile and bask in the glow of responsive, non-blocking code.

Constructors, as well as a few more things, are where the limitations of the tools appear and trip up even the average programmer, who is just trying to write a program to do his job.

Jeff also commented that one reason why BeOS failed to attract developers was because, like WinRT, the entire OS API was asyncronous, and writing anything beyond a utility was torture. I think for the most part it's a small learning curve, but the tools are much more approachable than they were 8 years ago. We'll see how Microsoft fares in the future.